If $G$ is a group of odd order, and $\chi$ is a character of a representation of degree 2, then there is an element in $s \in G$ such that $\chi(s)=0$
I have to decide whether this statement is true or false:
If $G$ is a group of odd order, and $\chi$ is a character of a degree $2$ representation of $G$, then there is an element $s \in G$ such that $\chi(s)=0$.
I think the statement is false, but I'm having trouble proving it. I supposed that $\chi(s)=0 \ \ \forall \ s \in G$. Then, the representation of degree $2$ of $G$, $\rho$, given by $\rho(s)= \begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & v
\end{pmatrix}$ is such that $x+v=0$ (because $\chi(s)=\text{tr}(\rho(s))=0$). The matrix $\rho(s)$ is conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix}
\omega & 0 \\
0 & \omega
\end{pmatrix}$ where $\omega$ is the $n$th root of unity, $n$ is the order of $G$. But from here I cannot develop to obtain a contradiction (assuming that the statement is indeed false). Any tips?

If you believe the statement is false then you want to exhibit a specific example of a group of odd order $G$ and a character $\chi$ of degree $2$ making the statement false. Have you tried playing with some examples yet? (Also, it's not true that the two eigenvalues of $\rho(s)$ are necessarily the same.)

The function $\rho$ given by $\rho(g)=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}$ for all $g$ in $G$ is a representation of degree two whose character satisfies $\chi(g)=2$ for all $g$. Perhaps the statement is meant to apply to irreducible characters?

But but but ... the degree of an irreducible character divides the order of the group, so a group of odd order can't have an irreducible character of degree two.

I think even more can be said, i.e. it NEVER happens that $\chi(s)=0$. If $\omega$ and $-\omega$ are both eigenvalues of $\rho(s)$, at least one of them has an even order.

So if you replace "representation" by "irreducible representation" in the question, the statement becomes vacuously true, and the answer is yes. It's a strange question!

@DerekHolt Perhaps this is at a point in a book where Burnside's Theorem has not been treated yet. That reminds me, there is no mentioning of "complex" representation, or any field for that matter.

@NickyHekster On reflection I think that the intended answer is that it is always false, as pointed out by Jyrki Lahtonen

Thanks! I think the path to the solution is in comment of @JyrkiLahtonen
